# Check that each level provides further levels

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of lots of `Serial_numbers`. Each `Serial_number` was measured before and after an `irradiation`, indicated by "0" and "1".

I would like to check my data frame if each Serial_number provides both data sets indeed. It's probably a plain request but I didn't come to a practical solution, yet..

```
  Serial_number Irradiated Amplification Voltage

1 912009913 0 1.002520 24.9681
2 912009913 0 1.004520 29.9591
3 912009913 0 1.005370 34.9494
4 912009913 1 1.005600 44.9372
5 912009913 1 1.006830 49.9329
6 912009913 1 1.006900 54.9625

7 912009897 0 1.004537 26.4681
8 912009897 0 1.007240 28.9191
9 912009897 0 1.008167 29.4183
10 912009897 1 1.009153 33.1763
11 912009897 1 1.010291 36.1843
12 912009897 1 1.021757 41.4690

...
```

Comment: What would be the expected output with this example ?

Comment: The best would be a list of Serial_numbers which lack one of both data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the unique Serial numbers which have the status `Irratiadet == 0` with those with `Irradiated == 1` and use `all()` to check if all matches are `TRUE`.

```
> df
   Serial_number Irradiated Amplification Voltage
1      912009913          0      1.002520 24.9681
2      912009913          0      1.004520 29.9591
3      912009913          0      1.005370 34.9494
4      912009913          1      1.005600 44.9372
5      912009913          1      1.006830 49.9329
6      912009913          1      1.006900 54.9625
7      912009897          0      1.004537 26.4681
8      912009897          0      1.007240 28.9191
9      912009897          0      1.008167 29.4183
10     912009897          1      1.009153 33.1763
11     912009897          1      1.010291 36.1843
12     912009897          1      1.021757 41.4690

> all(unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 0]) %in% unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 1]))
[1] TRUE
```

Afterwards, use `%in%` to extract the positions of the matched Serial numbers within the vector `unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 0])` and get those values with

```
> unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 0])[unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 0]) %in% unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 1])]
[1] 912009913 912009897
```

which, in case of `TRUE` for the `all()` check above, should be the same as `unique(df$Serial_number)`.

---

New approach. Here's a function which should do all the work:

```
FOO <- function(x, y){
  if(length(x) == length(y)){
    if(all(x %in% y)){
      print("All items matched.")
    }else{
      print(paste("Only in x: ", x[!x %in% y]))
      print(paste("Only in y: ", y[!y %in% x]))
    }
  }else{
    print(paste("Only in x: ", x[!x %in% y]))
    print(paste("Only in y: ", y[!y %in% x]))
  }
}
```

Just call it with `FOO(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 0], df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 1])` and it automatically checks which numbers are only in one of the two vectors.

Quick example:

```
> FOO(c(1, 2), c(1, 2))
[1] "All items matched."

> FOO(c(1, 2), c(1, 2, 3))
[1] "Only in x:  "
[1] "Only in y:  3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I guess it's not working correctly. I used "A<- unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 0])" and "B<- unique(df$Serial_number[df$Irradiated == 1])" and for A I have 989 and for B 1000 but above command line provides "TRUE".
Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Hm, in that case you'd need to switch the check to `all(B %in% A)`. I'll check if there's a better approach.

Comment: I tried it with a small data frame and it works, so I guess I have keep track on it where things happen.

Comment: You provided (very fast) what I needed, so thanks a lot! Nevertheless I would like to return if I don't proceed :)

Comment: ah, the command line with "all" results in a TRUE though it shouldn't but "unique(example$Serial_number[example$Irradiated == 0])[unique(example$Serial_number[example$Irradiated == 0]) %in% unique(example$Serial_number[example$Irradiated == 1])]" delivers the Serial_numbers which miss a set.

Comment: Yeah, that's nice! Thank you very much!